# What is "Enable Bitmap" on my Qnap NAS?

Tags: network-attached-storage

What is "Enable Bitmap" on my Qnap NAS?
Will it allow me to recover data in case of failures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitmap doesn't allow for a faster rebuild. It only allows a faster Sync. So in case a disk gets disconnected from your RAID and then connects after 10 mins. In this scenario with Bitmap enabled only the data that has changed in 10 mins will be synced.

If you do a rebuild of RAID with a new drive, there is no existing data on that new disk, Bitmap or no bitmap, it will take the same time for rebuild in this case.

Comment: This is very important news for the sake of this answer...
Can you back it up with some more official documentation?
What we got so far was:
https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Write-intent_bitmap

Comment: Yes, here is the official document from QNAP.

https://docs.qnap.com/nas-outdated/QTS4.3.5/en/GUID-7AE448C8-485F-4AD4-A03F-EB7A6AE9188E.html

Comment: Link to the official documentation for QTS 5.0.x: https://docs.qnap.com/operating-system/qts/5.0.x/en-us/raid-bitmaps-7AE448C8.html

Answer (score 7):

"Bitmap"  is used to allow faster RAID rebuild times, but you will be able to recover without it if you have a proper RAID level enabled.

Comment: I have RAID 5... So the only thing about it is speed, non increased safety, right?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. The bitmap is said to reduce the speed a litle during normal operation while speeding up recovery.

Comment: Do I have a chance to disable it later?

Comment: https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Write-intent_bitmap

Answer (score 5):

When an array has a [write-intent bitmap](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Write-intent_bitmap), a spindle (a device, often a hard drive) can be removed and re-added, then only blocks changes since the removal (as recorded in the bitmap) will be resynced.

Therefore a write-intent bitmap reduces rebuild/recovery (md sync) time if:

- the machine crashes (unclean shutdown)
- one spindle is disconnected, then reconnected

If one spindle fails and has to be replaced, a bitmap makes no difference.

A write-intent bitmap:

- does not improve performance
- may cause a degradation in write performance, it varies upon:

  - the size of the chunk data (on the RAID device) mapped to each bit in the bitmap, as expressed by cat /proc/mdstat. The ratio (bitmap size / RAID device size )
  - workload profile (long sequences of writes are more impacted, as spindle heads go back and forth between the data zone and the bitmap zone)
- can be removed/added at any time

Answer (score 3):

If I remember correctly, it allows you to recover data *faster.*  (Only in certain RAID scenarios though.)  Here's a [link](http://forum.qnap.com/viewtopic.php?t=13213) -ignore the bickering- that should help.

Comment: Nice link, though in fairness I feel that the bickering is fairly applicable in this case, too.

Comment: agreed, but not very suitable to helping everyone else get to the answer!